# Пример-иллюстрацию слова "хлестаковщина"

Tags: лингвистика

можете пожалуйста помочь привести пример-иллюстрацию слова "хлестаковщина" а то у меня  только со словом "хлестаков" получается составить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Перед девушкой он изображал себя ангелом во плоти, только и созданным для того, чтобы её очаровать, в общем разводил хлестаковщину и фанфаронство.

Или что-то в подобном стиле.

Answer (score 1):

Такая, например, иллюстрация:

Разберёмся, так ли безобиден Хлестаков и сама хлестаковщина? Хлестаковщина - вирус  современного  общества.

Answer (score 1):

В характере Хлестакова можно усмотреть различные черты, но есть и нечто главное, что мы и называем хлестаковщиной. Это безудержное, беззастенчивое фразерство и хвастовство в сочетании с крайней несерьезностью.  Это ложь естественная и непринужденная, в которую лжец верит сам, которая настолько абсурдна, что  не подвергается сомнению.

Интересный материал на тему хлестаковщины представлен в Интернете.

В наше время Хлестаков вполне может организовать какую-либо фирму, при этом он назовет ее обязательно Хлестаков и К. В его фирме все специалисты – ведущие, лучшие и выдающиеся. Фирма окажет вам  полный набор услуг для вашего бизнеса, ее офисы существуют в 450 странах мира. Есть  даже офис в неком островном государстве, где количество сотрудников готово посоревноваться с численностью населения. Если клиент спрашивает, занимается ли фирма тем или иным вопросом, ему всегда отвечают «да». Фирма всегда занимается всеми вопросами.
При этом совсем неважно, что сайт не отвечает требованиям современности. Ничего страшного, что офис без хорошего ремонта. Да, мы знаем, что тексты написаны коряво и с ошибками, но менять пока не будем». Зачем менять – сойдет и так.

http://www.lexpro.ru/blogs/view/2813

Answer (score 0):

Я бы назвала это "пылевглазапускание",
Ну а если говорить не авторским окказионализмом, то см. ниже.

Хлестаковщина — похвальба, бахвальство, хвастовство, фанфаронство, самохвальство, хвастанье, фанфаронада Словарь русских синонимов. хлестаковщина см. хвастовство Словарь синонимов русского языка. Практический справочник. М.: Русский язык …   Словарь синонимов

ХЛЕСТАКОВЩИНА — ХЛЕСТАКОВЩИНА, ы, жен. (разг.). Беззастенчивое, безудержное хвастовство [по имени Хлестакова, героя комедии Гоголя «Ревизор»]. Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949 1992 …   Толковый словарь Ожегова

хлестаковщина — хлестаков (хлестаковщина, хлестаковствовать) хвастун, зарапортовавшийся лгун Ср. Он весь ушел... в глупую, смешную рисовку, в хлестаковщину самого последнего сорта. П. Боборыкин. Три афиши. 5. Ср. Он сорвался с петель и уж немножко… …   Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона

Хлестаковщина — ж. Беззастенчивое, безудержное хвастовство, враньё. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000 …   Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой

хлестаковщина — хлестаковщина, хлестаковщины, хлестаковщины, хлестаковщин, хлестаковщине, хлестаковщинам, хлестаковщину, хлестаковщины, хлестаковщиной, хлестаковщиною, хлестаковщинами, хлестаковщине, хлестаковщинах (Источник: «Полная акцентуированная парадигма… …   Формы слов

хлестаковщина — хлестак овщина, ы …   Русский орфографический словарь

хлестаковщина — (1 ж) …   Орфографический словарь русского языка

хлестаковщина — ХЛЕСТАКО/ВЩИНА ы; ж. Неодобр. Беззастенчивое, безудержное хвастовство, враньё. Легкомысленное хлестаковство. Страдать от хлестаковщины. Уличить в хлестаковщине …   Энциклопедический словарь

Хлестаков. Хлестаковщина — Герой комедии Н.В. Гоголя Ревизор (1863) – лжец и хвастун. Имя его стало нарицательным; хлестаковство , хлестаковщина – беззастенчивое, хвастливое вранье. Словарь крылатых слов. Plutex. 2004 …   Словарь крылатых слов и выражений

Хлестаков. Хлестаковщина — крыл. сл. Герой комедии Н. В. Гоголя «Ревизор» (1863) лжец и хвастун. Имя его стало нарицательным; «хлестаковство», «хлестаковщина» беззастенчивое, хвастливое вранье

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам [примеры](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F5%EB%E5%F1%F2%E0%EA%EE%E2%F9%E8%ED%E0) из Нацкорпуса - в ассортименте. Наслаждайтесь!